# How to fix 'PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Pheanstalk\Exception\SocketException: Unknown error'

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I'm trying to set up a BeanStalkD client, using pheanstalk.

I can perform certain operations such as listTubes().

When I try and reserve a job off a beanstalkd queue I am getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Pheanstalk\Exception\SocketException: Unknown error in C:\SmartParking\vendo
>       r\pda\pheanstalk\src\Socket\FileSocket.php:49
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\SmartParking\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\src\Socket\FileSocket.php(91): Pheanstalk\Socket\FileSocket->t
>       hrowException()
>       #1 C:\SmartParking\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\src\Connection.php(84): Pheanstalk\Socket\FileSocket->getLine(
>       )
>       #2 C:\SmartParking\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\src\Pheanstalk.php(372): Pheanstalk\Connection->dispatchComman
>       d(Object(Pheanstalk\Command\ReserveCommand))
>       #3 C:\SmartParking\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\src\Pheanstalk.php(255): Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk->dispatch(Objec
>       t(Pheanstalk\Command\ReserveCommand))
>       #4 C:\SmartParking\SecondAttempt.php(22): Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk->reserve()
>       #5 {main}
>         thrown in C:\SmartParking\vendor\pda\pheanstalk\src\Socket\FileSocket.php on line 49

What do I need to do to resolve this problem?

I've tried:

Various versions of PHP, various version of pheanstalk, restarting everything including the BeanStalkD server itself.

This is all running on a brand Windows Server 2016, PHP is just being used as a scripting engine off the command line.

I am using PHP version 7.2 currently.

```
// Hopefully you're using Composer autoloading.
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
// Create using autodetection of socket implementation
$pheanstalk = Pheanstalk::create('127.0.0.1');

var_dump($pheanstalk->listTubes());

while(true){
  $job = $pheanstalk
  ->watch('alpr-alt')
  ->reserve();

  echo json_decode($job->getData(), true);
}
```

Comment: a little help investigating: in pheanstalk/FileSocket.php this `fgets($this->socket, 8192);` resolves to false and then throws that 'unknown Error'

Comment: Thanks man, that really helped me out.

I looked into this code and then realized I didn't have the sockets extension enabled in my PHP.ini.

I feel like a real idiot now. I wasted 2 hours on this problem :)

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question with detailed explanation what solved that issue. Could help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have sockets enabled in my `PHP.ini`

So I changed :

```
;extension=sockets
```

to

```
extension=sockets
```

If you're using PHP as part of a web server you'd have to restart it at this point.

And this fixed my problem.